# How can I create a power function in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, qemu, bootloader, real-mode

I'm trying to write an assembly function to convert ASCII decimal digits into hexadecimal values which can be easily used by the computer. Before showing my code, I have to point out that I'm working in 16-bit real mode (using AT&T syntax), therefore I have some limitations.

To achieve my goal, I wrote a "**power**" function which takes two arguments (BX as the base and CX as the exponent) and returns BX^CX into BX, or at least that's what I expected it to do. In reality, it works fine only once. For example:

```
    mov     $2, %cx
    mov     $10, %bx
    call    power

    mov     %bx, %dx
    call    printh       # Prints the value in dx

    dec     %cx
    mov     $10, %bx
    call    power

    mov     %bx, %dx
    call    printh       # Prints the value in dx
```

Here the first three lines work just fine, as they put 100 (0x64) into BX. Conversely, the other three lines put 10 (0xA) into the last 4-bit of BX, **leaving the old (0x60)** from 0x64 and producing a bad 0x6A as a result.
I've done many checks, so I'm quite sure this is the nature of the problem. Despite this, I couldn't come up with a solution. Moreover, the code of my "power" function is really redundant, and I would like to make it simpler. Here it is:

```
power:
        push    %ax
        push    %cx
        mov     %bx, %ax
        or      %cx, %cx
        jz      power_zero
power_loop:
        cmp     $1, %cx
        je      power_loop_end
        mul     %bx
        dec     %cx
        jmp     power_loop
power_loop_end:
        mov     %ax, %bx
        pop     %cx
        pop     %ax
        ret

power_zero:
        mov     $1, %bx
        jmp     power_loop_end
```

Recently, after assembling and trying my code in qemu, I got this strange error:

[image: Error in qemu]

I don't know whether it's somehow linked with this problem in my power function or not, since I had this problem also before this error appeared. In the end, I firmly exclude the error to be in my print function, which I tried successfully on many occasions.

I would like to know if someone of you knows how to fix this problem, and most of all, if someone can tell me what's going on, and how can my computer remember a value (such as the 0x60 from the first power call) I erased through a mov or a xor operation.

In case you want to try the code by yourself, here I put a fully executable code which I tried: https://github.com/LoZack19/bare_metal/blob/main/power/power.S

EDIT:
After reading your answers I think it is better if I include in my question also the code of the printh function, because, as you correctly stated, that the error was here, and that the power function had no problem:

```
        # printh(%dx)
        # dx: hex value to print
        # ==> converts the value stored in dx to ascii and prints it
printh:
        pusha
        mov     $0x05, %cx
loop_printh:
        cmp     $0x00, %dx
        je      end_loop_printh
        call    convert             # Converts the lower nibble (4-bit) of dx into an ascii character and stores it in HEX_OUT
        dec     %cx
        shr     $0x04, %dx
        jmp     loop_printh
end_loop_printh:
        mov     $HEX_OUT, %si
        call    printf
        popa
            ret
# [...]

HEX_OUT:        .asciz "0x0000"
```

Comment: Just reading through your code, I don't see any problems.  Could you post a complete [mcve] which someone could build and run and test?

Comment: There is a bug in your zero power case: you load 1 into `%bx`, but then jump to `power_loop_end` which replaces it with `%ax`, which contains the original base.  So attempting to compute `42^0` will return 42 instead of 1.  But that doesn't seem to be the case you're testing here.

Comment: That's surely an error, thanks, but it won't solve the main problem. If you want an MRE I have to give you the print function, which is a little too long. What I can do is to send a git-hub link with the whole code in order for you to give a better look at it.

Comment: You could edit the link into the question, so that anyone can take a look.  That's not ideal from the SO self-contained question philosophy, but better than nothing.  Or, if you can create an example to reproduce the bug without the print function by inspecting the result with a debugger, then that would suffice as well.

Comment: One other note that may or may not be related: the `mul` instruction is widening and produces a 32-bit result, of which the high half is in `dx`.  So your `power` function will overwrite whatever value is in `dx`, typically with 0 when your power doesn't overflow 16 bits.  That's not necessarily a problem, if the calling code is aware of it and doesn't have any important data in `dx`, but since you scrupulously save and restore `ax` and `cx` but not `dx`, I'm wondering if this is an oversight.

Comment: EUREKA, that's the problem. I read it in the intel manual but I didn't really and fully understand. I use dx to pass the argument to the print function.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's your problem, since you replace the contents of dx afterwards with `mov %bx, %dx`, so whatever `power` did to `dx` is irrelevant.  Unless the code you linked already includes your fix?

Comment: No, it doesn't, and as you foreshadowed the problem remains. But I really don't understand what it is. I'm going to deepen my understanding of the MUL instruction by reading the intel manual, since the only reasonable part I think I could be doing wrong is the multiplication.

Comment: Single-stepping in the Bochs debugger, `power` is leaving `0xa` in `bx`, just as it should.  I'm sorry to say it, but the bug must be in the print function which you have "firmly excluded".

Comment: You are right, and I think I found it out. The printh function refuses to update the digit to print when dx shifted to the right by x positions equals zero, where x is the multiple of 4 necessary to make dx zero by shifting. Awfully explained, but hopefully you'll understand.

Comment: Don't use a power function for this (it's too expensive because of the number of multiplications you end up with, and unnecessary/avoidable). Instead just do a `"value = value * 10 + next_digit`" loop to convert ASCII to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power function is just fine in this case (except for the unrelated bugs mentioned in comments).  When called with `bx = 10` and `cx = 1` it correctly leaves `10` in `bx`.  Single-stepping in a debugger is a good way to test this, and I found Bochs is a more convenient emulator than qemu for debugging 16-bit code.

The bug is in your "firmly excluded" print function, specifically at `printh`.  Consider what happens when `dx` contains a value less than or equal to `0xf`.  After the first iteration of `loop_printh`, the low nibble has been shifted out of `dx`, and so `dx` is now 0.  Thus the test at `loop_printh` will exit the loop instead of iterating a second time.  So the high 3 nibbles will never be written to `HEX_OUT`, which will therefore still contain whatever characters were left behind as the high nibble from the previous print, here `006`.

Your `printh` needs to iterate the loop four times no matter the input, to ensure that `0`s are written for all the high nibbles.  Your test for the loop thus probably wants to be based on the value of the counter `cx` instead.

> how can my computer remember a value (such as the 0x60 from the first power call) I erased through a mov or a xor operation.

Because you never actually erased it :-)